# Не обновляются данные в бд?

Tags: php, mysql, ajax

Моей проблемы не увидел, либо плохо искал. Есть объект по клику на который меняется 1 его параметр и записывается с помощью ajax  в таблицу. Проблема в следующем: Параметр меняется нормально, но вот в базу данные не записываются.

```js
$('#mod').click(function() {
  var a0 = this.getAttribute('value');
  if (a0 == '11') {
    this.setAttribute('value', '12');
  } else {
    this.setAttribute('value', '11');
  }
  var pr1 = 'a0';
  var pr2 = '2';
  $.ajax({
    type: 'post',
    url: '../system/proc3.php',
    data: ({
      m: pr1,
      d: pr2,
    }),
  })
})
```

```html
<input id='mod' value='11'>
```

В proc3.php обработчик следующий:

```html
<?
if (isset($_POST['m'])) 
{
$da_is = $_POST['m'];
$da_nm = $_POST['d'];

if($da_is == 'a0'){
 $mand = $_SESSION['nLog'];
 $da_mm = $da_nm;
 $query55 = mysqli_query($link, "SELECT id,a_1 FROM o_tr1 WHERE `id`='{$da_mm}'");
 $row5 = mysqli_fetch_array($query55);
 $p_s = $row5['a_1'];
  if($p_s == '0'){
   $s_s = $p_s+1;
   mysqli_query($link, "UPDATE `o_tr1` SET `a_1`='{$s_s}' WHERE `id` = '{$da_mm}'");
   }else{
    $s_s = $p_s-1;
    mysqli_query ($link, "UPDATE `o_tr1` SET `a_1`='{$s_s}' WHERE `id` = '{$da_mm}'");
    }
}
}
?>
```

При проверке самих запросов в бд все работает нормально. Данные так же корректно уходят.

Comment: `вот в базу данные не записываются` - так и запрос `INSERT` тут отсутствует......... а зачем вот эта секретная хакерская манипуляция `$da_mm = $da_nm;` ?  а где используется `$da_is` ? а если вывести всё таки вывод ошибок и посмотреть что выводится после каждого из запросов?

Comment: @АлексейШиманский а update это не запись? перезапись.

Comment: вероятно у вас не проходит проверка `if($da_is == 'a0'){`

Comment: @Jean-Claude перезапись, а не запись же)) считаю все же что это обновление данных, а вставка/запись это всё же insert

Comment: Никогда, слышите, никогда не называйте переменные понятными именами. Пишите код как можно запутаннее. Чем больше вложенных условий и неочевидных переприсваиваний - тем лучше. Только так можно гарантировать, что вас никогда не уволят, ведь никто другой не сможет сопровождать этот код.

Comment: да да, еще постоянно добавляйте вставки чистого js в код jquery. чтобы он был длиннее. Используйте относительные пути в URL, Делайте очень длинные отступы, чтобы код читать можно было только на 4К дисплеях, или не делайте, чтобы запутать врага. И, конечно, вставляйте значения переменных прямо в тело sql запроса, и не проверяйте результаты выполнения функций

Comment: если вы уверены, что данные в пхп файл вообще передаются, то начните с замены `mysqli_fetch_array` на `mysqli_fetch_assoc`

Comment: Алексей. Таблица уже существует на тот момент. Поэтому и update. Эта "хакерсая манипуляция" - извините проверял получаю ли я данные в запрос или нет. (мусор). А как вывести. У меня не получается проверить все то что происходит в отдельном файле обработчике.
terran, просто я не профессионал, потому вопрос и задаю.

Comment: @teran я понял свою ошибку. благодарю...

Comment: Отступы в коде php - Это сделал данный сайт. я тут ни причем ...

Comment: там в целом все ваши манипуляции с sql кодом можно свести к одному update запросу, без каких либо селектов, if-ов и вычислений в пхп. а-ля `update o_tr1 set a_1 = (case when a_1 = 0 then 1 else a_1 - 1 end) where id = 2`

Answer (score 0):

Собственно глупая получилась ситуация. Решением которой стала проверка полностью кода обработчика. 
Что в итоге вскрыло кучу ошибок различного характера. Начиная от пропуска ; до не объявленных переменных. И исправление данных ошибок привело в рабочее состояние код.

p.s. за все замечания благодарю. Буду учиться дальше ...